# Operating on a heterogenous list with a shared state and inter-element communication

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a Haskell program that is made up of unique systems operating on some shared data (and their own data), and possibly reading from each other's data. I'm trying to find an abstraction that lets me:

1. Concisely model the passing and modification of the shared state, 'data'
2. Model the modification of a system's own state
3. Easily add another system

Here's a mockup, in psuedo-code:

```
(system1, data) = runSystem system1 () data
(system2, data) = runSystem system2 (system1) data
(system3, data) = runSystem system3 (system1, system2) data
(system4, data) = runSystem system4 (system2) data
```

by which I mean...

```
-- system1 modifies itself and also 'data'
-- system2 modifies itself and also 'data', and reads from system1
-- system3 modifies itself and also 'data', and reads from system1 and system2
-- system4 modifies itself and also 'data', and reads from system2
```

So, 'data' can be modeled with the State monad. That's the easy part I guess. And the psuedo-code actually isn't that bad, except to implement it I need to basically write out the tuple of systems 3 times:

```
loop :: (System1, System2, System3, System3) -> State Data ()
loop (system1, system2, system3, system4) =
    do
       system1' <- runSystem1 system1
       system2' <- runSystem2 system2 (system1)
       system3' <- runSystem3 system3 (system1, system2)
       system4' <- runSystem4 system4 (system2)
       loop (system1', system2', system3', system4')
```

So to add a system into the mix I need to change code in 4 separate places (the type signature, the deconstruction, the actual run call, and the loop call).

I actually did this with heterogeneous lists using ExistentialQuantification and a System type class, but then I couldn't figure out how to pass in systems to each other, since the runSystem functions would need different type signatures.

In lisp this is easy-- I can just add the system to a list of systems and there's no type checker to complain.

Is there a way to simplify this code using monads or arrows or some other technique?

Comment: Thinking out loud: A single algebraic data type System would not be desirable because the implementation of the individual system (including its data) should be defined in a separate file with the rest of the system code. But maybe I could have an ADT System = System1 System1Data | System2 System2Data etc..., where System1Data is defined in a separate file. That might let me use a heterogeneous list? The sheer number of different approaches to solve a problem in Haskell makes my head spin.

Comment: Have you considered using `STM` to implement shared state between systems? This seems like a good use case, and you'll be able to run your systems concurrently as opposed to the lock-step method you've used here.

Comment: Also the "heterogeneous list with existential quantification and typeclass" approach is an anti-pattern commonly used by people who are trying program in Haskell the same as they would in a dynamic language. There are almost always cleaner, more idiomatic ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: cdk: I'm not familiar with STM but I'll check it out. Thanks very much for the note about heterogenous lists. It felt like an inflexible hack, but I'm not experienced enough yet to see the normal Haskell way of doing things.

Comment: @whooops You might want to read [this](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) blog post for an example of not using existential types and instead just using a normal haskell data type and abstracting over the functions that operate on them instead.

Comment: @bheklilr that's very interesting. I loved this quote: "There is no difference between “some object, where the only thing we know about it is that it has a draw method” and a simple draw method itself. We have no way of getting any more information about it, so why not just throw out that information in the first place." I'm trying now to refactor in a more functional way.

Comment: I think this is my fundamental problem: I want a common interface to a collection of items that hold different types of data. That is easy until I want to get that data out of the item and use it somewhere else, which is apparently impossible under Haskell's type system. Once you map a function over a list of items, there's no way to distinguish between the output. I guess that makes sense from a compiler's point of few, but I don't know else to model the problem in order to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

My ultimate problem was that I wanted to treat a list of items homogeneously (as Systems), but  I wanted each system to contain it's own particular type of data. In Haskell this is normally illegal.

My (somewhat inelegant) solution was to declare the data inside a system as [Dynamic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html).

```
data System = System { run :: [Dynamic] -> SharedData -> (System, SharedData),
                       sysData :: Dynamic,
                       dependencies :: [Dynamic]
                     }
```

Before folding over the system list with a runSystem call, I resolve the dependencies in each system by setting a list of Dynamic values.

```
syncSystems :: [System] -> [System]
syncSystems [s1, s2] = [s1,
                       primeSys s2 [s1]
                       ]

primeSys :: System -> [System] -> System
primeSys s sLst = s { dependencies = map sysData sLst }
```

Then I use foldAccumL to fold the SharedData and map each system to a new version of itself.

Each system's run function casts its dependencies to what it knows them to be to use them. (More info here: [3 A Universal type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections#A_Universal_type))